# What is $l_i$ in The wetted perimeter

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The [wetted perimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetted_perimeter) can be defined mathematically as

$$P=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} l_i$$

what is this means that $l_i$ is the length of each surface in contact with the aqueous body?

the length of each surface of what is in contact with aqueous body?

Comment: Can you expand on your question a bit? What sort of systems are you talking about and where did the equation you mention come from?

Comment: Someone added a link to Wikipedia in your question. Can you explain what about that page is unclear to you?